# Created an application based on django and wants to read mails of an user (But without presence of user) using graph API

Tags: django, azure, graph

I have an application in Django framework. I want to read mails of an user without it's presence using graph API. 
I want this functionality for one user only. 
I came to this solution that if i get mail.read permission from 'application permissions', then it would work. 
But my admin is not giving this by saying... It will provide access of all user's mails of this organization.
So question how i can achieve this functionality, because i don't want to read mails of all users from active directory. I just want this functionality for one user.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access

Comment: Good to hear :) You can add an answer to this question with some info on how you managed it to help people who run into the same issue.